# Screen causes SSH to drop

Tags: networking, 16.04, ssh, screen

I'm trying to re-attach to a screen through an SSH connection running on a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 16. However, whenever I re-attach to the screen, it shows about half of the screen, and then my SSH connection freezes, and I have to kill my terminal, open a new one, and reconnect. At that point, the connection is again fine, until I re-attach to the screen, at which point it freezes again.

What's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Similar 'freezes' are often due to MTU size. Aren't you by any chance going through VPN connection ? Try to change MTU size to 1300 and see if it helps.
I use screen on RPi with Ubuntu 16.04, no problem reattaching.

To change MTU size use sudo ip link set dev vpn0 mtu 1300